# PHP - SQL Array insert code skipping first value

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I've developed a function for printing variables into a mysql database.

It appears to work great except it will skip the first value when recording values in the sql. However, all 3 appear with the `echo` command. In other words, values 1 2 and 3 print with echo - but only 2 and 3 go into the database!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$allcharacters = $xml->xpath('///result/rowset/row/@name');

foreach($allcharacters as $alts) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","master");
    $sql="INSERT INTO masterlist (charactername) VALUES ('$alts')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "Found $alts<br />";
```

Sample data being inserted:

```
Found Tiamat's Shadow
Found Troyd23
Found Gore Innovater
Gore Innovater
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two things: first, can you show sample data that you're inputting into the database (i.e. - value of `///result/rowset/row/@name`); second, have you tried using a prepared statement (maybe the character(s) break the query)?

Comment: http://www.repercussus.org/apply/test.php output result is visible here ie. the value of the echo "Found $alts"; Unsure what you mean with the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sanitizing your input when you're inserting it into the database.

The `'` in the first item, `Found Tiamat's Shadow`, breaks your SQL-query so it actually fails to insert; this is confirmed by your question's problem "it will skip the first value".

With [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), you have two options to fix this.

The first is you can escape your data using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","master");
foreach($allcharacters as $alts) {
    $alts = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $alts);
    $sql="INSERT INTO masterlist (charactername) VALUES ('" . $alts . "')";
    ...
```

Using this function, any "unsafe" characters will automatically be escaped when inserting into your database.

The second method is to use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). This will require a little more code, however, doing this will almost-always guarantee you don't forget to do it by accident. Here's a sample with a prepared statement:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","master");
foreach($allcharacters as $alts) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO masterlist (charactername) VALUES ( ? )");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $alts);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    ...
```

This method is far-more robust than the previous as it will escape data based on the data-type of the column. It may be a bit more than what's needed for your specific use-case, but it never hurts to be in the habit of using prepared statements =]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the input and answer!